# how to calculate number of nodes in a tree given algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, tree, discrete-mathematics

I have a problem that i need help with. Im given:

```
int sum(int[] array, int first, int last)
{
 if (first == last)
 return array[first];
 int mid = (first + last) / 2;
 return sum(array, first, mid) + sum(array, mid + 1, last);
}
```

Question: Determine a formula that counts the numbers of nodes in the recursion tree.

So, I got the recursion equation:
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + dn

And for example for an array of length 8, number of nodes in the recursion tree would be 15, which would indicate the number of nodes in a tree would be 2n-1 where n is the size of array.

I was wondering if my thinking is correct and can the 2n-1 formula be applied to any case? Also, is there a general way to calculate number of nodes in a recursion tree given a recursive algorithm?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is **dn**, and what code represents that cost?

Comment: @trincot **dn** probably represents the cost of addition operation and some other constant time operations in the function. Because, the term **2T(n/2)** is for the recursion calls and whatever operations are left (comparison, computation of **mid** and the addition and return) all takes constant time. T(n) = 2T(n/2) + c

Comment: I just find it suspicious that there is **n** appearing in **dn**. Just wanted to make sure it is not dependent on the value of **n**.

Comment: @trincot It should not depend on **n**.

Comment: I agree, I wish the OP would give an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
       2
     /  \
    1    1    // 2(n) - 1 = 2(2) - 1 = 3 seems to match!

        3
      /  \
     2    1
   /  \
  1    1      // 2(n) - 1 = 2(3) - 1 = 5 which seems to match
```

Working out a few other examples, the formula 2(n) - 1 seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The number of nodes in a full, balanced tree of height *h*, where each non-leaf node has *c* children is
*(c^h-1)/(c-1)*

In particular, in a full binary tree, we have *c=2*, and therefore the number of nodes is *2^h-1*.
As the number of leaves in a full binary tree is *L=2^(h-1)*, this also implies that the number of nodes is *2L-1*.